# Coverage run with GCC does not produce data

Tags: fortran, profiling, code-coverage

I have a Fortran program I would like to profile with GNU coverage. So I compiled the program with GCC 11.2 with these coverage options:

```
-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

Also, I add flags to disallow compiler to inline the code:

```
-fno-inline -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-default-inline
```

I turned off `lto` and add `-lcgov` to linker. This setup worked well for a sample program I proved. But when I tried to use it for the program I am interested in it did not generate any *.gcno files, just nothing. Execution, however, exited well (0 exit code) producing correct results.

My question is, how can I find where the problem is. Without an error message, I don't know where to start. It is a rather bigger program ~10 MB of source code, can that be a problem? Also, it heavily depends on `MKL`, can the external library be the problem? Once I accidentally mixed compile time and runtime environments and it complained about the version of `libgcov.so`, so something is working after all. Or do you have any other suggestions for coverage profiling?

Comment: Two sets of files are typically generated for coverage `*.gcda` and `*.gcno` that are typically stored in the same folder as where the object files are generated. You would likely want to build the library in `debug` mode rather than selectively turning off optimization flags. These are the coverage linker flags `-fcf-protection=full -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -static-libgcc --coverage -lgcov` I do not remember at the moment why I have added each to the library. But each one was added for a good reason, certainly. Easy to read gfortran manual to find out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this was the case. I never would imagine they would be created in the folder where the .o files are stored. I turned off only inlining options, but works now perfectly.